# What magic is behind Powershell converting a DirectoryInfo or Fileinfo type to string and can this be replicated in custom types?

Tags: powershell

```
cd $home
foreach ($dir in gci d*) {
    $dir
}
```

gives the output:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\User


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-r---         1/19/2023  11:14 PM                Desktop
d-r---         1/13/2023   1:31 PM                Documents
d-r---         1/30/2023   5:35 PM                Downloads
```

However,

```
cd $home
foreach ($dir in gci d*) {
    [string]$dir
}
```

or

```
cd $home
foreach ($dir in gci d*) {
    "$dir"
}
```

give the output

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop
C:\Users\User\Documents
C:\Users\User\Downloads
```

The string conversion automatically selects the FullName property out of all the various string-typed properties in the DirectoryInfo type.

The story gets even more interesting with:

```
cd $home
foreach ($dir in gci -Directory) {
    "$dir"
}
```

This outputs only the directory names, *not the full names*.

#### Questions

1. How does PowerShell know to automatically select the FullName property of the DirectoryInfo type whenever it's cast to a string?
2. Is there some attribute attached to FullName that performs this magic in the background?
3. Can we use this attribute in our own custom types, like a default property when converted to a primitive?
4. Why is it when no path is selected, the string conversion selects the Name property?

```
74|PS(5.1.19041) C:\Users\....\wsPowerShell\Modules [230131-09:47:18]> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: No magic involved. The FileInfo class returns the `DisplayPath` property in its overload of `ToString()`. You can check the [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs,4ee673c1a4ecad41) page for every underlying C# class and its implementation.